# Where are the 'Recents' user pictures saved?

Tags: image, avatar, osx-mavericks

I have set a user picture for my user account.

I can see it when selecting the user picture in the system preferences *Users & Groups* and in the tab recents.

Where are the user picture saved on my mac on **mavericks**?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at

```
/Users/grafvonmalotky/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent Pictures
```

There are the original and the cropped version of every image, very cool.

The default ones are at

```
~/Library/User Pictures
```